# India e-visa granted but missing information on the form. Am I okay to travel?

Tags: india, eta, e-visas

I already have recived my ETA, status: granted

**BUT** on the application form file generated on my computer I can see that are missing some information (I forgot to write the postal code of my employer addres and th postal code of the first hotel I'll stay in India)

Now I am really afraid that on my arrival at Delhi airport they can denied me the entry in the country!

Someone can help me please?

Comment: My wife traveled to India twice on e-visa.  She had some missing info on her second visa acceptance.  She contacted the folks via email and it was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

While you didn't include postcodes for several addresses, that oversight did not influence e-visa application and the electronic visa was granted. It would not affect the process in India; on arrival, you go to the e-visa booth, your biometric information obtained, and your passport stamped.

[For any assistance](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html) call 24/7 e-Visa support center at +91-11-24300666 or send email to indiatvoa@gov.in